# c++ QObject::connect converting to new Qt5 Syntax

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, qt5, winsock

I am fairly new to QT so bear with me.  I have a server application that I must connect to a port on and get a packet of data which is basically a string of xml content.  The communication is ancient and will work fine returning data with the example from https://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/ however I am trying to convert this example to the new Qt5 connect syntax and am failing horribly, any help or insight is greatly appreciated.  Here is an example of the response from the service packet that is received.  I need to grab that xml into memory and operate on it.  However the syntax is beyond me.  Forgot to mention that I am trying to run this and compile on Windows 10 Visual Studio 2015 using command line: cl /EHsc test.cpp

This appears to be the magic that needs changed:
`if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)`

```
D:\git>test

Initialising Winsock...Initialised.
Socket created.
Connected
Data Send

Reply received

<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<zoneServer>
<name>SuperNova</name>
<status>up</status>
<users>
<connected>0</connected>
<cap>3000</cap>
<max>0</max>
<total>0</total>
<deleted>0</deleted>
</users>
<uptime>142751</uptime>
<timestamp>1609481513051</timestamp>
</zoneServer>
```

Here is my code in QT:

```
SOCKET s;
char *message , server_reply[2000];
int recv_size;

qDebug() << "\nInitialising Winsock...";

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    qDebug() << "Failed.";
    exit;
}

qDebug() << "Initialised.\n";

//Create a socket
if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    qDebug() << "Could not create socket : " << WSAGetLastError();
}

qDebug() << "Socket created.\n";


server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.116");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 44455 );

//Connect to remote server
//try to connect...


int status = connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));

if(status < 0)
{
    qDebug() << "connect error";
    exit;
}

qDebug() << "Connected";

//Send some data
message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
{
    qDebug() << "Send failed";
    exit;
}
qDebug() << "Data Send\n";

//Receive a reply from the server
if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    qDebug() << "recv failed";
}

qDebug() << "Reply received\n";

//Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
qDebug() << server_reply;
```

However in the editor I receive:
`.cpp:407: error: no matching member function for call to 'connect'`

After Unrelated Includes:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#endif

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library
```

Comment: this is the line I'm trying to convert utilizing the examples as a starting point. ```int status = connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));```

Comment: That `connect` is a WinSock https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect call, has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: I realized that but wasn't sure what I'm doing incorrectly, I need it to work on Windows and Linux 32 bit and do not necessarily need winsock at all but that is what windows uses, please note the application i am working with does run on Windows and Linux and is designed and compiled in QT Creator, so it kind of related to Qt I would say.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that line? What error are you getting? (The equivalent POSIX connect call has the same syntax - WinSock provides a mostly POSIX interface so apart from initialization it should mostly work.)

Comment: I am getting no matching member function to call 'connect' in qtcreator i tried changing to QObject::connect but that did not work either.

Comment: [Edit] your question to add the complete error message, and make sure you have the right includes.

Comment: [QTcpSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) will make your life easier if you want to make your code cross platform. To fix your problem you probably just need `::connect` to use the global connect function rather than the `QObject` member

Comment: literally hours of nonsense for Alan to give me my answer it was ::connect pulled the right method thanks!

Comment: If you provide a [mre] then you'll get less nonsense, one of the key missing bits of information was that your code is inside a `QObject` class, the full error message would have helped too

Comment: Hmm at first I thought this needs no C tag but I added it back...